# How does qgis render vector layer on screen ? How can I do the same in a mobile device

Tags: qgis, vector, layers

Can you please tell me how does qgis software render the vector layers on the screen. I have a geojson file and I need to map its contents on the screen just like qgis does but without using base map layer or map tiles being downloaded whenever I drag etc. To be more precise, if I want to take the qgis software's map display area and put it on a mobile screen, how do I do it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, this question seems to be both very broad and not GIS-centric. Since QGIS is open aource, there is no reason you can't review *exactly* how it interacts with the operating system graphics libraries. With some research, you will likely find that simply porting the code would be far in excess of the capabilities of a mobile device. This in turn will lead you to web-based mapping applications.